# Trouble with jitpack/gradle in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, jitpack

I'm still getting started with gradle, but I found jitpack to allow for including dependencies across my github repos.

I'm having issues getting dependencies to resolve, though.  Some releases work, but other times I get "could not resolve."

I have managed to reproduce this with a couple of github repos:
I set up a repo to be depended on: https://github.com/bdleitner/dummy-dependency
and one to depend on it: https://github.com/bdleitner/dummy-client

From jitpack, I can see the build log for the 0.1.3 release of dummy-dependency:
https://jitpack.io/com/github/bdleitner/dummy-dependency/0.1.3/build.log
where it seems that everything is successful.

when logged in to jitpack, it can see this release and provides the compile statement:

```
compile 'com.github.bdleitner:dummy-dependency:0.1.3'
```

but even when I include that in the gradle.build file for dummy-client, 
I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.bdleitner:dummy-dependency:0.1.3.
Required by:
  com.bdl:dummy-client:1.0-SNAPSHOT
> No cached version of com.github.bdleitner:dummy-dependency:0.1.3 available for offline mode.
> No cached version of com.github.bdleitner:dummy-dependency:0.1.3 available for offline mode.
> No cached version of com.github.bdleitner:dummy-dependency:0.1.3 available for offline mode.
```

I figure I'm probably missing something small and dumb, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, I somehow managed to switch my gradle settings to offline mode (not sure how)... but unchecking that option appears to have fixed the issue.

Sorry to bother everyone.